# Retornar physicalDeliveryOfficeName do AD usando LDAP com Java

Tags: java, active-directory

Estou criando uma aplicação em Java que integra com o active directory. Mas estou tendo problema para retornar um dado em específico: o campo Office (Escritório - physicalDeliveryOfficeName).

Teoricamente, a lógica dele deveria funcionar de forma semelhante aos outros métodos que tenho, mas sempre pego `NullPointerException` ao tentar retornar este campo. Os outros métodos que retornar outros dados (sAMAccountName, cn, givenName, mail e afins todos funcionam certinho). Vou colocar o código aqui embaixo.

Este é o método `getGivenName(Pessoa)`, um dos que funcionam corretamente.

```
    public String getGivenName(Pessoa p) throws NamingException { 
            String givenName = "";
            try {
                NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> result = this.searchUser(p); 
                if (result.hasMoreElements()) { 
                    SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) result.next(); 
                    Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                    givenName = attrs.get("givenName").toString(); 
                    givenName = givenName.substring(givenName.indexOf(":") + 1);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return givenName; 
        }
```

Este é o método que uso para conectar ao AD, com o query LDAP nele. Também funciona corretamente

```
public NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchUser(Pessoa p) throws NamingException { 
        String filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + p.getUsername() + "))";

        return this.dirContext.search("DC=umc,DC=br", filter, this.searchCtls); 
    }
```

Este é o método que falei, que retorna nulo e me prejudica.

```
public String getPhysicalDeliveryOfficeName(Pessoa p) throws NamingException {
    String physicalDeliveryOfficeName = "";
    try {
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> result = this.searchUser(p); 
        if (result.hasMoreElements()) { 
            SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) result.next(); 
            Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
            physicalDeliveryOfficeName = attrs.get("physicalDeliveryOfficeName").toString(); 
            physicalDeliveryOfficeName = physicalDeliveryOfficeName.substring(physicalDeliveryOfficeName.indexOf(":") + 1); 
        }

        physicalDeliveryOfficeName = physicalDeliveryOfficeName.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return physicalDeliveryOfficeName; 
}
```

Neste campo, é armazenado o número da chapa do funcionário, e preciso deste número como chave primária para um cadastro numa base de dados. Mas, por conta do problema que falei, não consigo retornar o dado, sei lá eu por quê. A imagem abaixo tem mais detalhes das informações e como são mostradas.

[image: Dados do AD]

Comment: Ad seria active directory?

Comment: Exato, @diegofm. Estou conectando com o Active Directory usando LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique na seção **Users** ou **Usuarios**.
Alguns não irão possuir este atributo.